# C/C++ printf() before scanf() issue

Tags: c, printf, output, scanf

I'm using Eclipse to code in C/C++ and I'm struggling with what might be something pretty easy. In my code below I use `printf()` and after `scanf()`. Althougth `printf` is written before `scanf()` the output differs. I was able to find out something about similar issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=218). But I wasn't able to solve it. Any ideas?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int myvariable;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &myvariable);
    printf("%d", myvariable);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Enter a number:1
1
```

Instead I get:

```
1
Enter a number:1
```

Comment: Your question is confusing: "In my code below I use printf() and after scanf()". "printf is written before scanf()". it's not what you put in the code. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: You are right, sorry.
I meant, that first I want to print something, in this case:
printf("Enter a number:");
Then read number from keyboard. And then print the number into the console. But instead after running the programme nothing prints out and the programme waits for input. After receiving the input the programme prints out both "Enter a number:" and the number itself.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe I have wrong plugins or something. As I wrote before, I'am new to this, and I just followed few tutorials on how to set C/C++ in Eclipse. Maybe it'll be better to remove everything and try to start from fresh beginning.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of: [printf not printing to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870059/12149471) (which was posted 14 hours easlier)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your output is being buffered.
You have 4 options:

1. explicit flush

   `fflush` after each write to profit from the buffer and still enforce the desiredbehavior/display explicitly.

   ```
    fflush( stdout );
   ```
2. have the buffer only buffer lines-wise

   useful for when you know that it is enough to print only complete lines

   ```
    setlinebuf(stdout);
   ```
3. disable the buffer

   ```
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
   ```
4. disable buffering in your console through what ever options menu it provides

---

#### Examples:

Here is your code with option 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int myvariable;
    
    printf("Enter a number:");
    fflush( stdout );
    scanf("%d", &myvariable);
    printf("%d", myvariable);
    fflush( stdout );

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int myvariable;

    setlinebuf(stdout);    

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &myvariable);
    printf("%d", myvariable);

    return 0;
}
```

---

and 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int myvariable;

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);     

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &myvariable);
    printf("%d", myvariable);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The first option works. But still, it's seems like pretty messy solution considering writing longer and more complex code. I mean, it's like doubleing the work. I'll try the fourth though.

Comment: If you don't care about buffering and its *possible* benefits you can go with option 3. It's a one-liner (set only once in your program and done). Option 4 is an alternative if you do not want to or cannot change the code at all. Option 2 probably won't reliably echo your input if there is no newline.

Comment: Each of the `printf("%d", myvariable);` lines would be better with a newline at the end.  Only omit the newline if you are consciously building up a single line of output piecemeal.

Comment: This answer would be better if it used `setvbuf(..., _IONBF, ...)` instead of `setbuf` and used `setvbuf(..., _IOLBF, ...)` instead of `setlinebuf`. `setvbuf` is part of the C standard library; the other two are not.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so finally I used something similar to what @zsawyer wrote as an option labelled 3.
In my code I inserted this line:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

As a first line in main():

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    int myvariable;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &myvariable);
    printf("%d", myvariable);

    return 0;
}
```

I got it from [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732).