# Why my program combines two printf commands?

Tags: c, eclipse, printf

So here is my program. It is suposed to write out square of some intiger.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
     int a;
     printf("Type an intiger.");
     scanf("%i", &a);
     printf("Square of that intiger is %i", a*a);
     return 0;
}
```

When i run a program in Eclipse it first requires me to input a number.I put in 5. And then as output it gives me

```
Type an intiger.Square of that intiger is 25.
```

It should first print "Type an intiger" and then the rest. But it just combines two printf commands. What is the problem?

Comment: it should be "integer"

Comment: using the latest eclipse C/C++ version that I've just downloaded, a copy-paste of your code works just as one'd expect it to. Perhaps [download it here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplersr1), and then try again.

Comment: i have found an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/eclipse-c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [newline character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) - `printf("Type an intiger.\n");`

> In computing, a newline, also known as a line break or end-of-line
>   (EOL) marker, or simply break, is a special character or sequence of
>   characters signifying the end of a line of text.

Also format specifier for integer is `%d`

```
 scanf("%d", &a);
 printf("Square of that intiger is %d", a*a);
```

Comment: No problem is that i want my programm to do following:
"Type an intiger" 
5 
"Square of that number is 25" 

But right now i have that i type in 5 and then it combines into one single output "Type an intiger.Square of that number is 25"

Answer (score 2):

If you want it on separate lines you can always add '\n' to the string to get a new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
     int a;
     printf("Type an intiger.\n");
     scanf("%i", &a);
     printf("Square of that intiger is %i", a*a);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: No problem is that i want my programm to do following:
"Type an intiger" 
5 
"Square of that number is 25" 

But right now i have that i type in 5 and then it combines into one single output "Type an intiger.Square of that number is 25"

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 problem in it. First, if you input the integer, it should be `%d`. Example :

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

The second, after the input, you should print `\n`. So, it will be like this `printf("\n");`. Take a look at my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int a;
    printf("Type an intiger.");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nSquare of that intiger is %d", a*a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No problem is that i want my programm to do following:
"Type an intiger" 
5 
"Square of that number is 25" 

But right now i have that i type in 5 and then it combines into one single output "Type an intiger.Square of that number is 25"

Answer (score 0):

In code::blocks it compiles fine anyway put a \n at the end of the first printf and change %i with %d