# scanf before printf - C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

So, I have a `printf`, that asks for the users middle initial, then I have a `scanf` under that, then I output the users middle initial. My problem is that my `printf` is displaying after my `scanf`

**C Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char middleInitial;

    printf("What is your middle initial? ");

    scanf(" %c", &middleInitial);

    printf("Middle initial %c", middleInitial);

}
```

So as you can see, there are two `printf`'s. My `scanf` is running before my first `printf` displays the question.

**Example (This is what I'm getting in my terminal)**

```
$ ./a.exe
c
What is your middle initial? Middle initial c
```

**What I want**

```
$ ./a.exe
What is your middle initial? c
Middle initial c
```

**By the way, the c is what the user inputs**

Comment: printf uses `buffered I/O`, so in this case the buffer won't be automatically flushed because there's not a newline in your format string you pass into printf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ printf() before scanf() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `fflush(stdout)` before your call to `scanf()`.

Comment: Answer explains what to do, but not why.  Answer would benefit with such an explanation.

Comment: because there's no '\n' in the printf (done on purpose), the buffer doesn't get automatically flushed - it needs to be explicitly.

Comment: Note: even with a `'\n'`, `printf()` is [not specified](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359) to flush the output either, although that commonly does flush `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

type `fflush(stdout);` just before your first `scanf()` should be after first `printf()`

In my windows pc I face the same issue. If you use different operating system you might not need it.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.