# C/C++ printf() and scanf() reversed when running the program

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
enum abcd{aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,z};

typedef struct stct{
    abcd eAbcd;
    int x;
} stct;
typedef struct indexx{
    int size;
    struct stct *addr;
} indexx;

void add_item(indexx *idx);
stct read_in();

int main()
{
    indexx idx = {0, NULL};
    int op;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n1. add item\n4. quit\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &op);
        switch (op)
        {
            case 1:
                add_item(&idx);
                break;
            case 4:
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Please enter a correct number\n");
        }
    }
}

void add_item(indexx *idx)
{
    stct *newdata;
    newdata = (stct *) realloc(idx->addr, idx->size*sizeof(stct));
    if (newdata)
    {
        idx->size ++;
        idx->addr = newdata;
        idx->addr[idx->size-1] = read_in();
    }
    else
        printf("No memory\n");
}

stct read_in()
{
    stct temp;
    int ab;
    temp.eAbcd = z;
    while (temp.eAbcd != aaaa && temp.eAbcd != bbbb && temp.eAbcd != cccc && temp.eAbcd != dddd)
    {
        printf("select(1-4):\n");
        scanf("%d", &ab);
        ab-=1;
        switch (ab)
        {
            case 0: temp.eAbcd = aaaa; break;
            case 1: temp.eAbcd = bbbb; break;
            case 2: temp.eAbcd = cccc; break;
            case 3: temp.eAbcd = dddd; break;
        }
    }
    scanf("%d", &temp.x);
    return temp;
}
```

It was supposed to print out `select(1-4):` before scanf(), but when I compile and run the program, I got this:

```
1
select(1-4):
```

(`1`is what I entered.)

I have tried the solutions in [C/C++ printf() before scanf() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue) and none of them works for me.

Comment: So you added for example `fflush()` like adviced there?

Comment: Where are you running this one ?

Comment: @Sridharan running on fedora 26, compile using g++ 7.1.1

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes, I have tried all solutions from the answers to that question

Comment: I think Sridharan's question was more about whether you **run** this in a standard terminal ... or maybe inside some IDE.

Comment: @FelixPalmen bash 4.4.12, directly run the complied file

Comment: Well, can't reproduce (and I'm pretty sure nobody else can). Maybe you don't show **all** your code. Turning this into a [mcve] by adding `#include <stdio.h>` and a `main` function works as expected.

Comment: Can't reproduce, what I would do was to fiddle with termios commands and getchar to see what going on

Comment: @FelixPalmen I have put up the codes

Comment: @Sridharan I have put up the codes

Comment: Post your **full** input and **full** output of the program

Comment: I still can't see how you get the effect you describe, but the code is definitely broken, your `while` loops will not work as expected when you enter something that can't be parsed as a number by `scanf()`. For those `scanf()` related problems, you might want to read my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). Side note: `scanf()` treats all whitespace the same and `\n` **is**  a whitespace, so if you meant to require a newline in the input -> it doesn't do that, it matches any sequence of whitespace.

Comment: @FelixPalmen this is part of my assignment, and we were only taught to use scanf to input.

Comment: @Paradox this is unfortunate, because it's close to impossible to provide reliable interactive input with `scanf()`. The least you should do is check the return value of `scanf()`  and just exit your program with an error if it doesn't return `1` when you expect exactly one conversion (like with `"%d"`). Btw, this code doesn't compile: `error: unknown type name ‘abcd’`. Are you accidentally using a C++ compiler to compile this?

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes I am using g++ to compile

Comment: @Paradox don't. If it is C code, use a C compiler. C and C++ are quite different, although they have a common subset. Here you have **invalid** C code that *happens* to be valid C++ code. Change `enum abcd{aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,z};` to `typedef enum abcd{aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,z} abcd;` to make this valid C. As for your bug, I'm writing an answer explaining it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ok, I'll fix it, thank you very much

Comment: @FelixPalmen Technically, any two languages have a common subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in **this** line:

```
    scanf("%d\n", &op);
```

The `\n` here is just a *whitespace character* (like  and `\t`) and `scanf()` treats any whitespace character the same: They match a *sequence* of whitespace in the input stream of any length (including 0).

If you enter a number and hit enter, you **do** enter a newline and this newline is indeed matched by `\n`, it would also be matched by  or `\t`. But you don't **want** to match it: `stdin` is by default *line buffered*, and as `scanf()` would optionally match more whitespace characters, it will **wait** for more input to see whether more whitespace is following and only return once you hit enter again because with *line buffering*, input only becomes available at a newline.

In a nutshell: This `scanf()` won't complete until you hit enter again, so `add_item()` isn't even called until you do.

The simple solution here: remove the bogus `\n` from the format string.