# scanf function not working on GCC ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, scanf

I'm starting to write a C code after a gap of almost 10 year. I was teaching my sister and unfortunately got stuck at a very basic scanf() function for a simple interest program on Ubuntu.

My program is not giving any compilation error but it's not showing anything on screen

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int p,n;
    float r,si;
    printf("enter values of p,n,r");
    scanf("%d %d %f",&p,&n,&r);
    si = p*n*r/100;
    printf("%f" , si);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scanf ... not working"?  You never check the return value, so how do you know it's not working?

Comment: It works for me! Enter the values separated by whitespace, not commas

Comment: You're probably not seeing the output because it's on the same line as the next shell prompt. Add a newline at the end: `printf("%f\n", si)`

Comment: Several answers suggest either printing a newline or calling `fflush(stdout)` after the first `printf` call. That's certainly a good idea, but on my Ubuntu system, when I run the program from a shell prompt, the program works without that; the prompt is printed correctly. And the answer is printed, but without a newline, so the next shell prompt appears on the same line. When you say it's "not showing anything", do you mean the "enter values ..." prompt doesn't appear? How exactly are you running the program?

Comment: To be clear: Does the "enter values" prompt appear? If it does, then your statement that "it's not showing anything on the screen" is incorrect. If it doesn't, then you're having problems before the program even gets to the `scanf`, so you shouldn't assume that the `scanf` is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common "issue" when trying to `printf()` and `scanf()` after one another. The operating system buffers `stdin` and `stdout` in order to increase performance and only flushes them when necessary. You can explicitly flush stdout by calling `fflush(stdout);` right after `printf()`.

See [C/C++ printf() before scanf() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue).

Your code would end up looking like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int p,n;
    float r,si;
    printf("enter values of p,n,r\n");
    fflush(stdout); // Force stdout to be flushed
    scanf("%d %d %f",&p,&n,&r);
    si = p*n*r/100;
    printf("%f" , si);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: As important as, or more important than, the `fflush(stdout)` is adding a newline to the end of the `printf()` statement.  That gets the output to the screen in a sensible, timely manner.  You could add a `fflush(stdout)` too — but the newline is still a good idea.  (And printing the input values is also a good idea, as is checking that `scanf()` returns 3, because if it doesn't, you've got an input failure and uninitialized variables in the calculation.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just not looking at your console properly. The output "si" is getting printed on the same line as your first printf since you do not have a newline inserted at the end of it.

Comment: There will be a newline at the end of the user's input line.

Comment: They're probably not seeing it because it's on the same line as the next shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked perfectly for me in my Ubuntu system.This may be because of the mistake of the IDE you are using.

Try running code in `Ubuntu` this way:-

- save file as `program.c` on desktop.
- open terminal and type `cd Desktop` *(navigate to desktop)*.
- compile code by typing `gcc -o program program.c` .
- run program by typing `./program`.

Comment: So you're proposing that the OP is only compiling the program, not actually running it?  That's plausible, but you could more clearly say that if it's what you mean.

Comment: I think the problem is unlikely to arise from a buggy IDE though.

Comment: I had similar experience in codeblocks.

Comment: That does not mean it's the IDE that is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> not showing *anything* on screen

(emphasis added), I take you to mean that when you run it, it's not displaying the data-entry prompt you're printing.  This would be because the standard output is line-buffered by default when connected to a terminal -- it will buffer the output in memory before printing it, until either the buffer is filled, or (because *line* buffered) a newline is output, or the stream is closed (including when the program terminates normally).

One way to cause the prompt to be displayed, therefore, is to append a newline to it:

```
printf("enter values of p,n,r\n");
```

Another is to use an output function that automatically appends a newline:

```
puts("enter values of p,n,r");
```

If you want to ensure that the output appears even though no newline has been sent then you can flush the stream (standard output in this case) instead:

```
printf("enter values of p,n,r: ");
fflush(stdout);
```