# What is the difference between nodelay() and cbreak() in ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

What is the difference between `nodelay()` and `cbreak()` in ncurses ? And why use these functions because we have `getch()`! If i have understand `getch()` permits to get the key directly just after the user hit the key. So `nodelay` and `cbreak` is useless isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

They are two completely different functions.

From the documentation:

> Normally, the tty driver buffers typed characters until a newline or carriage return is typed. The cbreak routine disables line buffering and erase/kill character-processing (interrupt and flow control characters are unaffected), making characters typed by the user immediately available to the program. The nocbreak routine returns the terminal to normal (cooked) mode.
>
> ...
>
> The nodelay option causes getch to be a non-blocking call. If no input is ready, getch returns ERR. If disabled (bf is FALSE), getch waits until a key is pressed.

So `cbreak` is if you want to disable line buffering, which you may want for many reasons. One is to avoid having to use `fflush(stdout)` after each printout. With line buffering enabled, a printout will normally not be visible on screen until a newline character is printed.

The description of `nodelay` is pretty self explanatory. `getch` will not wait, but return instantly irregardless if any key is pressed or not.

Comment: So cbreak() disable line buffering but we are in blocking mode and nodelay() causes getch in particular to be a non-blocking call ?

Comment: Ok ok but i don't understand why when i execute that code => int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    printw("Blah");
    refresh();
    while (1);
} It will display Blah although i don't use cbreak ?

Comment: No, but printw flushes after every printout (or something else that has the same effect) which is not the case for printf.

Comment: Or maybe it doesn't. I don't really know. One important thing here is that this is a typical thing where it works they way it should *most of the time*. I tried the exact code here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16877264/6699433 and I did not manage to reproduce the problem.