# How to get all currently available input with ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

Let's consider that example:

```c
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>


// ...
// Some functions like `contains` and `getBuff`
// ...

int main() {
  initscr();                        // Init curses mode
  // ... Do some initialisation

  int *input;                       // Input buffer

  while(1) {
    getBuff(input);                 // Get all characters currently available into buffer
    if(contains(input, 'q')) break; // If there is 'q' in buffer - break
    // ... Do something with buffer
    usleep(100000);                 // Wait some time
  }

  endwin();                         // Exit curses
  return 0;
}
```

Here, in the loop the program waits some time, and after it gets all input got while it was sleeping.
The main problem is in `getBuff()` — I don't know how to make it.

I've tried using `halfdelay()` and `while(getch() != ERR)`, but it doesn't work fine. If the user presses any key and does not release it, the program stops at the loop.

So, `getBuff()` might get all input **available at the time of its call**, not later.

Comment: Does the linked duplicate answer your question? [Create a function to check for key press in unix using ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025891/create-a-function-to-check-for-key-press-in-unix-using-ncurses). If not, could you explain what it's missing?

Comment: @JohnKugelman No, it's not duplicate. In their case they were not getting currently available at buffer. They were continuously getting input even after the old buffer was fully red.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You said `halfdelay()` didn't work. What about `nodelay()`?

Comment: Perhaps no. It works the same — it reads input while it sees something.

Comment: Could you show your code using `nodelay()`? Let's figure out why it isn't working for you.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is incorrect.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245062/what-is-the-difference-between-nodelay-and-cbreak-in-ncurses/56245112#56245112) is more appropriate.

Comment: Looks like `nodelay()` is working. But both "duplicate questions" seems not a duplicate, even if the answers help. Thanks for help!