# How to implement a "press enter" command?

Tags: c++

How do I manage to implement a "press enter" command instead of having the user write something? I am terribly new.

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int year;
    cout << "this is a leap year checker press enter.... \n";
    //I want to have a press enter command over here.
    cout << "put year here: \n";
    cin >> year;
    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
       cout<<year<<" is a leap year";
    else
       cout<<year<<" is not a leap year";
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please decribe what having a "press enter command" would look like. What would be a story in which it is visible? What should it cause? In, contrast, how does not having one look like? What is the difference?

Comment: Why is reading in a string, or a whole line, and ignoring it not what you want?

Comment: I don't know but if this is what you want you can simply make `cin >> [anything];` and wait for the user to press enter.

Comment: Do you mean you want to enter the values on the command line, like this: `myleapyearprogram 2012`? That would involve [using `argc` and `argv` to get the arguments](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html), which you would then have to convert from a c-string to an integer.

Comment: @Yunnosch Like I said I am entirely new. I just wanted to see how it would be inserted, but I probably should post that when I am one month or longer in to c++.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read a whole line of input, and ignore it, you can use [`std::cin.ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please press <ENTER> to continue: ";
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

    std::cout << "You have pressed <ENTER>.\n";
}
```

Comment: You don't need the manual flush. By default, `cin` and `cout` are `tie()`'d together, so that reading input will automatically flush any pending output first.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Although I have never experienced it myself, [on some platforms, it is necessary to manually flush the output buffer before input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue). This is probably because [§7.21.3 ¶3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p3) does not guarantee that the output is flushed manually before input. However, this probably only applies to C and not C++, as [29.7.4.2.4 of the ISO C++20 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/input.output#istream.sentry) does make such a guarantee.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: [continued from previous comment] Therefore, you are probably right that the explicit flush is not necessary. For this reason, I have removed it.

Comment: those links are for C I/O not C++ I/O. What I said is true for C++'s `cin`/`cout` streams specifically.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Ah, yes, you are right that C++ probably also has the same issue when using C-style I/O. It is only C++-style I/O that provides the guarantee that flushing is not necessary (unless you untie the streams).

Answer (score -1):

any time you need to wait for enter just use `getchar()` function to wait for write char to console and press enter

Comment: Are you suggesting calling `getchar()` in a loop, until the function call returns `'\n'`? You may want to add a short code example.

Comment: No do not use it in loop. just place it. this function will pause program until user press ENTER any other chars will print in console window

Comment: @Bitor that is incorrect. `getchar()` will return the next key entered, whatever it happens to be. It will not wait for ENTER specifically. So it would have to be called in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement something like this as under:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void PressEnterToContinue(std::string text = "Press enter to continue...")
{
    std::cout << text;
    while (true)
    {
        char key = getchar();

        if (key == '\r') break;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    PressEnterToContinue();
}
```

Or if you want to press any key to continue, you can just do the following:

```
std::cout << "Press any key to continue..."; 
char key = getchar();
```

Comment: `<conio.h>` is not a standard C++ (or standard C) library, and it is best avoided entirely. Please do not recommend using it ever.

Comment: I've edited the answer to use a different function. Thanks for informing me of that. Never knew `conio.h` was not a part of the std C/C++ library.

Comment: `\r` worked in my case, `\n` didn't.

Comment: @SolvedGames try using `cin.get()` instead of `getchar()`