# printf not print on the console in eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, s, i;
    do {
        printf("n= "); // here is the problem ?
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n<100 || n <= 0);
    s = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i <= n) {
        i = i + 2;
        s = s + i;
    }
    printf("s=%d", s);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I ran it in eclipse c/c++ and it not print "n=" first. But when I run it in another IDE like DEV-C++ or VS 2017, it run well. When add this line after printf and I ran like I expected.

```
fflush(stdout);
```

What is the problem here ?

Comment: There is no language C/C++! The code looks like C, so why spam the C++ tag? And what did you not find? There are tons of dups already!

Comment: The Eclipse console often needs a signed invitation to flush.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf not printing to screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870059/printf-not-printing-to-screen)

Comment: Why not put `"n= "` in `scanf`itself?

Comment: @AravindVoggu Because `scanf` does not write out to `stdout`. It only reads (from `stdin`).

Comment: @SiggiSv but it did.. Probably that's just the case with my compiler?

Comment: but it run well in other IDE like visual studio. what is the difference ?

Comment: @NguyễnTiếnThiên buffering is disabled in some environments. If buffering is disabled, `printf` statements are immediately output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ printf() before scanf() issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue)

Answer (score 6):

### `printf` doesn't print to screen unless buffer is flushed

Looks like your streams are buffered. Data you write to `stdout` and other streams is buffered and all output once you flush your buffer. This allows for better performance as IO is slowest among all your CPU operations.

At this point, you have at least these options:

1. Explicitly flush the buffer by calling `fflush( stdout )` every time you use `printf`
2. Disable buffering `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`
3. Flush buffer by using newline `\n` at end of `printf` string Ex: `printf("n= \n");`

Your code worked in some environments probably because buffering is disabled there.

Comment: this code:    printf("n= \n");  doesn't work for me. And when we flush stdout buffer. data transfer to stdout ?

Comment: @NguyễnTiếnThiên You mean to say `printf("n= \n");` doesn't print or it makes your input go to a new line and you don't like it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for that. I thought some compilers allowed `scanf` to print to `stdout`. but as I see, `scanf` is not meant to do that. So I removed that suggestion. Yeah, that `%s` is a typo.  
Thanks :)