# printf does not print on the console in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, console, printf, settings

This question is similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098943/printf-not-print-on-the-console-in-eclipse), but the answer and comments there do not help me.

Yes, it (still/sometimes) doesn't print! Even if "fflush(stdout);" is in there, in the code.

Actually it printed but no longer. I'm guessing there is some project/debug "option" set.. (maybe yes, maybe not).

So, how can I find where else, other from fflush(), could the caveat be? (Eclipse has so many settings, and so little help about what are they all for..)

Once again (code fragment):

```
        printf("prompt>");
        fflush(stdout);
```

Nothing is on the console. The code just continue running ignoring this.

[Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Ver:2019-12(4.14.0) Build id:20191212-1212]

Comment: I'd like to add: there is a (~15 years old) Eclipse bug: poor Ctrl/D processing. The program just hangs if pressed.
There were lots of discussions, and solutions - for Linux, for Java, for Python..
The conclusion/diagnosis was that this (Ctrl/D issue) is a problem around Eclipse/Windows. 

My case!: Win10/WmWare/Ubuntu/Eclipse. Ctrl/D prevents from debugging! 

As a result I'm here, and can't use Eclipse anymore...

My utility has a second interface - a virtual console. If I run it, everything works, then my case seems to be a pure Eclipse case.

Comment: What else I did: Eclipse/menu/project/properties/run_debug_settings


restore defaults

This did not help! Fantastic. Shall I re-assemble a project or deinstall Eclipse (unsure)?

Comment: reopening the console with Window->Show View->Console

didn't help.

Comment: >>Go to "Window > Reset Perspective", that will reset the window settings to default. 

This didn't help too.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found an answer myself.

->properties->run/debug->(allocate console checkbox)

Appeared to be unchecked.

Who did it - do not know. Why the "reset perspective to default" did not help - strange.

Half a day lost.

Thanks.

Closed.