# Eclipse: inputs are done before showing the printf statements

Tags: c, eclipse, io

It is an extremely simple program that does an addition of two integers. I don't know why, but when I run the program, the console requires me to input the two integers and then shows the printf() statements, even though I wrote each printf() before each scanf().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int a, b;

    printf( "Enter first integer\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &a );

    printf( "Enter second integer\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &b );

    int sum;
    sum = a + b;

    printf( "Sum is %d\n", sum );
}
```

I'll attach what the console shows me as a picture.

[image]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Working as expected for me. Try running explicitly in a terminal outside IDE.

Comment: Your code is fine and produces the prompts before the numbers are entered. Generally these type questions are due to line-buffering of output, but you force the output stream to be flushed by including the `'\n'` following each prompt. What compiler and OS are you using? For grins, you can add `fflush (stdout);` after each `printf` and before each `scanf` to confirm... There may be a platform that has some odd implementation that I have not run across yet..

Comment: Looks to be an eclipse oddity, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098943/printf-not-print-on-the-console-in-eclipse), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue).

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the documentation of your operating system and compiler. For *every* function you use but didn't write, read its documentation, perhaps [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). In particular, read [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and notice that it can fail.

Comment: This is a known eclipse issue and has several posts here on SO regarding it. Try to look for it and you'll find many questions very soon.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's quite a famous issue for the Eclipse IDE. The duplicate has more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct in function call sequence. It looks like some `stdin`/`stdout` wrong handling in Eclipse console. It [happens](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=199219) with this IDE sometimes. I can suggest to do next possible things to try avoiding this problem:

- Update Eclipse to latest version (if it is not done yet);
- [Install](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/terminal) another terminal plugin to Eclipse and try with it;
- Try another IDE: [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), [CodeLite](https://codelite.org/) or do it [online](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler).