# Program didnot show printf statement

Tags: c, loops, output, printf

This code is about creating a value based on the value previously obtained in lectures, so the important variables here are just sks(credits), b, sum, sumsksb, and nh. The program will process it into a final score of the average sum of credits divided by the number of credits called IP (rt variable). But I want to display the previously inputted name in the IP(rt) output.
This it the code without output name:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i, N, kodemk, sks, b, sum, sumsksb, jsks;
    char mk, nh, name;
    float rt;
    printf("Jumlah mata kuliah ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Nama anda ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    sum=0;
    jsks = 0;
    for(i=1; i<=N; i++){
        
        printf ("Masukkan kode mata kuliah ");
        scanf("%d", &kodemk);
        printf("Masukkan Nama mata kuliah ");
        scanf("%s", &mk);
        printf("Masukkan jumlah sks ");
        scanf("%d", &sks);
        printf("Masukkan Nilai Huruf mata kuliah ");
        scanf("%s", &nh);
        if(nh == 'A'){
            b = 4;
        }
        else if(nh == 'B'){
            b = 3;
        }
        else if(nh == 'C'){
            b = 2;
        }
        else if(nh == 'D'){
            b = 1;
        }
        else if(nh == 'E'){
            b = 0;
        }
        sumsksb = sks * b;
        sum = sum + sumsksb;
        jsks = jsks + sks;
    }
    rt = sum/jsks;
    printf("IP %.2f ", rt);
}
```

and if I run it, the printf output of IP(rt) at the end appears and there are no problems
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDHS9.png)

But when I want to printf the name

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i, N, kodemk, sks, b, sum, sumsksb, jsks;
    char mk, nh, name;
    float rt;
    printf("Jumlah mata kuliah ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Your Name ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    sum=0;
    jsks = 0;
    for(i=1; i<=N; i++){
        
        printf ("Masukkan kode mata kuliah ");
        scanf("%d", &kodemk);
        printf("Masukkan Nama mata kuliah ");
        scanf("%s", &mk);
        printf("Masukkan jumlah sks ");
        scanf("%d", &sks);
        printf("Masukkan Nilai Huruf mata kuliah ");
        scanf("%s", &nh);
        if(nh == 'A'){
            b = 4;
        }
        else if(nh == 'B'){
            b = 3;
        }
        else if(nh == 'C'){
            b = 2;
        }
        else if(nh == 'D'){
            b = 1;
        }
        else if(nh == 'E'){
            b = 0;
        }
        sumsksb = sks * b;
        sum = sum + sumsksb;
        jsks = jsks + sks;
    }
    rt = sum/jsks;
    printf("Nama:\n%s", name);
    printf("IP %.2f ", rt);
}
```

The output of name and rt didnot show and the program end before showing it
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faiwh.png)

How to showing the name?

Comment: Related: [printf not printing to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870059/printf-not-printing-to-screen).

Comment: Did your compiler not warn you about `name` being the wrong type?

Comment: `name` is a single character, it cannot be used with the `%s` specifier. Perhaps you want to make `name` an array  of characters instead? Looks like you have the same problem with some other variables too.

Comment: Unlike `name` and `mk`, `nh` *is* actually being used as a single `char`, so you can use this `scanf` call to input its value : `scanf(" %c", &nh);`. The space before `%c` is needed to read and discard any initial whitespace characters because `%c` is one of the few `scanf` format specifiers that does not discard initial whitespace automatically.

Comment: @ScottHunter no, there is no error and warn, the output just show when i just use print IP, but when i add printf("%s", name), the output of both of them didn't show. Just end after I input 'Nilai huruf mata kuliah'.

Comment: If true, you need a better compiler.

Comment: For `name` and `mk`, you need to declare them as arrays of `char` with a suitable length, e.g. `char name[100];` and `char mk[100];`. Then you can read them with `scanf("%99s", name);` and `scanf("%99s", mk);`. (The maximum field width is 99 because an array of 100 `char` can hold a null-terminated string of maximum length 99.) Note that `%s` will stop when it sees a whitespace character after a non-whitespace character. If you want to read a full name including spaces, then you will need `scanf(" %99[^\n]", name);` to skip initial whitespace and then read up to 99 non-newline characters.

Comment: @IanAbbott ok, i will replace it

Comment: thanks all, i have try your suggestion,  and it worked, there were several small errors that occurred, such as the IP displaying the address after changing the nh, and the IP results not matching, but I was able to fix it and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take array of name variable and try

Answer (score 0):

It's surprising that a memory access violation is not reported.

The declarations should read more like:

```
char mk[4], name[76]; /* allows 3 character mata code
                      and name up to 75 characters */
char nh;
```

With `nh` remaining a single char, its `scanf` statement needs its format updated to `%c`.

```
scanf("%c", &nh);
```

That should make a crash less likely.

Comment: You need a space before `%c` so it will skip leading whitespace like the newline from the previous input. `scanf(" %c", &nh);` [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: @RetiredNinja this is worked, thanksfully to you all

Answer (score 0):

After try your suggestion, this code work, thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int i, N, kodemk, sks, b, sum, sumsksb, jsks;
    char nh;
    char nama[67], mk[10];
    float rt;
    printf("Jumlah mata kuliah ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Nama anda ");
    scanf("%s", &nama);
    sum=0;
    jsks = 0;
    for(i=1; i<=N; i++){
        printf ("Masukkan kode mata kuliah ");
        scanf("%d", &kodemk);
        printf("Masukkan Nama mata kuliah ");
        scanf("%s", &mk);
        printf("Masukkan jumlah sks ");
        scanf("%d", &sks);
        printf("Masukkan Nilai Huruf ");
        scanf(" %c", &nh);
        if(nh == 'a' ){
            b = 4 * sks;
        }
        else if(nh == 'b'){
            b = 3 * sks;
        }
        else if(nh == 'c'){
            b = 2 * sks;
        }
        else if(nh == 'd'){
            b = 1 * sks;
        }
        else if(nh == 'e'){
            b = 0 * sks;
        }
        sumsksb = b;
        sum = sum + sumsksb;
        jsks = jsks + sks;
    }
    rt = sum/jsks;
    printf("Nama: %s\n", nama);
    printf("IP %.2f ", rt);
}
```

[Final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQfNz.png)